# SharePoint List Json Formatting and grouping

Tags: sharepoint-online

Following json list formatting display the list records as shown below -

[image]

JSON Formatting used is -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "customRowAction": {
      "action": "defaultClick"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "class": "='ms-bgColor-white ms-fontColor-white--hover'"
    },
    "style": {
      "margin": "10px",
      "padding": "10px 10px 10px 10px",
      "border-width": "1px",
      "border-radius": "10px",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "border-color": "green",
      "cursor": "pointer",
      "float": "left"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "text-align": "left"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$Test]",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "='ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular '"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**But when the list view is grouped by some field then the output is not displayed as expected. How this can be fixed ?? Expanding each group should display records for that group below only. As shown below group header and list items gets mixed in one row.**

[image]

When all groups are collapsed display is correct.
[image]